Movie with a roller coaster which takes one back in time
I cannot for the life of me remember the name of this movie from my childhood. This is what I remember.

a girl goes to her grandmothers farm
in the barn she finds an old roller coaster
when she rides the roller coaster it takes her back in time
when she first travels in time she is in a school and the teacher hits her with a ruler I think

I know it's not much to go on but I would appreciate it so much if someone could help me find the name of this movie.

When was your childhood? What year/decade do you feel the movie is from?

Sounds like Split Infinity from 1992, though a few details are a bit off. From IMDb:

AJ is living 1992 and life is all good so it seems. [...] Then her grandfather Frank comes for a visit. He tells her about his sister Amelia Jean who passed away in the 1930s from pol[i]o. [A]fter hearing the story AJ goes to the barn, which is the only thing that was saved with the house from the Great Depression.
AJ's brother comes and joins her in the barn loft before almost falling out the window. AJ yells at him and she tries to follow him to apologize WHEN she falls and the story changes... She wakes up in 1929 and meets her grandfather (who is her Brother), she is now in Amelia Jean's shoes.

When she wakes up in 1929, she's in class and the teacher there is spanking students with a paddle. In the end, she goes back to the present in a sort of makeshift rocket suspended on a wire in the barn. Here's the trailer:




That's It!!!!! :) Thank You Soo Much!! You are amazing!! :)

@Erica No problem. Don't forget to click on the check mark to mark this as 'solved'.
